# What is the difference between these 2 dfas for binary strings ending with 00?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

[image]
The first one is from unreputed youtuber whereas second one is from reputed university called adiuni course of theory of computation.

Now I know what that second figure means, it means it also accepts $\in$ as initial state=final state, but

1. how I don't know that. This dfa should accept all binary divisble by 4. But how is nothing(it is not zero mind that) divisible by 4?
2. Why I don't know that. I am making a dfa for binary numbers divisible by 4 and adiuni professor told that binary numbers that end with 00 are divisble by 4. So I googled about dfa ending with 00 and got this. I am personally more comfortable at first figure as it is more inituitive to me.

How is $\in$ divisible by 4? What does that even mean?

Comment: `nothing [is not zero]` (reminds me of difficulties ancient Greek philosophers are assumed to have had.) How do you know, how would I without access to the definitions (here: *binary*) to use?

Comment: I would be inclined to agree with you, I don't know what divisibility even means for the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The first DFA is correct, and the second is incorrect. When we say a string *ends in 00* we imply that it must have at least two characters. So, it can't be the empty string, and it also can't be the single 0 string.

> This dfa should accept all binary divisble by 4. But how is nothing(it is not zero mind that) divisible by 4?

I agree, and this is a good way of thinking about it. However, note that we aren't writing a DFA for the set of binary numbers divisible by 4 (that would include 0), but rather for the set of binary sequences which end in two zeros. So it is slightly different.